# K-Nearest Neighbors in pure Python

Tags: python, clustering

I want a general criticism on this code. Using external modules is not an option, I can only use what comes with CPython.

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import Sequence, NamedTuple

Coordinates = Sequence[float]

class KNNPoint(NamedTuple):
    coords: Coordinates
    classif: str

def predict(target: Coordinates, points: Sequence[KNNPoint], k: int) -> str:
    '''
    Applies the K-Nearest Neighborhood algorithm in order to find the
    classification of target.

    - target: Single data to be classified.
    - points: Collection of data which classifications are known.
    - k: The number of closest neighbors to be used.
    '''
    def distance(p: KNNPoint) -> float:
        return sum((a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(target, p.coords))

    neighbors = sorted(points, key=distance)
    counter = Counter(x.classif for x in neighbors[:k])

    return counter.most_common(1)[0][0]
```

If you'd like to run it, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ihavenonickname/bf494fa0cfb62885cd672d29f948f0d8) has everything ready. it uses a dataset of mobile phones. (This gist shall not be reviewed)

Comment: If you want any speed from this, you will have to use external modules. I don't think you will get even close to the performance of [`sklearn.neighbors.KDTree`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.KDTree),  which is a better data structure for this than a list and also implemented in C, otherwise.

Comment: @Graipher Yes. Also, running the same thing on pypy3 takes only 35% of the time taken on cpython.

Comment: I know you explicitly stated the gist shall not be reviewed ... but ... you really need to normalize your data!  The clock speed (GHz) has a range of 2.5 where as the RAM (MB) has a range of 3742.  When you compute the distance between locations, any difference in clock speed will become noise compared to a small difference in RAM.  For example, the entire clock-speed range of 0.5 GHz to 3.0 GHz is a 6.25 square-distance, where as a tiny change in RAM, say from 256MB to 512MB results in a square-distance 10,000 times larger.

Comment: @AJNeufeld I didn't think about that. I'll normalize the data and see if it helps, however I won't report my results here because it's not part of the review. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumption: k << N, where N = len(points)

There is no need to sort the *entire* list of points!

Instead, take the first `k` points, and determine their distance values, and sort them.  Then, for each success point:

- determine its distance,
- if it is smaller than the maximum,

  - discard the maximum, and insert the new point in the sorted list.

Sorting N points by distance is O(N log N); creating and maintaining a sorted list of `k` smallest elements is only O(N log k), which should be considerably faster.

I'm not sure if [`heapq.nsmallest()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest) is built into CPython or not ...

```
k_neighbours = heapq.nsmallest(k, points, key=distance)
counter = Counter(x.classif for x in k_neighbours)
```

---

Well, I'm disappointed to see `heapq.nsmallest()` performed up to 40% worse that `sorted` on CPython, but I'm happy to see PyPy validates my assertion that you don't need to sort the entire list.

Continuing with that thought, `bisect.insort()` may be used to maintain a list of the k-nearest neighbours so far:

```
    neighbours = [(float('inf'), None)] * k
    for pnt in points:
        dist = distance(pnt)
        if dist < neighbours[-1][0]:
            neighbours.pop()
            bisect.insort(neighbours, (dist, pnt))

    counter = Counter(pnt.classif for dist, pnt in neighbours)
```

This gave me 4% speedup over `sorted()[:k]` with your gist sample set.

Significant, but not impressive.  Still, it was enough encouragement to press on an look for other inefficiencies.

How about the `distance()` code.  It gets called a lot; can we speed it up?  Sure!

```
def predict(target: Coordinates, points: Sequence[KNNPoint], k: int, *,
            sum=sum, zip=zip) -> str:

    def distance(p: KNNPoint) -> float:
        return sum((a - b) ** 2 for a, b in zip(target, p.coords))

    # ...
```

Instead of searching the global scope for the `sum` and `zip` functions, they are saved as variables `sum`, `zip` in the local scope, along with `target`, for use in `distance()`.  Total improvement: 6%.

Applying the same `sum=sum, zip=zip` change to the original code, without the bisect.insort() change, also speeds it up by 2%.

Further, adding `insort=bisect.insort` to the function declaration, and using `insort(neighbours, (dist, pnt))` in the function body also provides a minor improvement.

Finally, I was concerned about `neighbours[-1][0]`.  Looking up the first tuple of the last element in the array seemed inefficient.  We could keep track of this in a local `threshold` variable.  Final total speedup: 7.7%.

```
neighbours = [(float('inf'), None)] * k
threshold = neighbours[-1][0]
for pnt in points:
   dist = distance(pnt)
   if dist < threshold:
      neighbours.pop()
      insort(neighbours, (dist, pnt))
      threshold = neighbours[-1][0]
```

YMMV

Comment: In CPython, `nsmallest` performed equal to `sorted` for small `k`; and 40% worst for large `k`. Using PyPy, `nsmallesr` performed 50% better than `sorted` for both small and large `k`.

Comment: And yes, it's built into CPython.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `insort`. I just found out that changing `(a - b) ** 2` to `(a - b) * (a - b)` causes a 28% performance improvement on CPython, while makes no difference on PyPy (I guess PyPy JIT compiles both versions to the same thing).

Comment: Wow!  Good find!  Makes my micro optimizations almost laughable.  Nice low hanging fruit!